# How do I get LCID of a culture from Short name in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, cultureinfo, lcid

The CultureInfo class in Silverlight does not expose LCID property unlike its .NET counterpart. How do I get the LCID for a culture from its short name? e.g. getting 1033 as LCID by giving "en-US" as input without maintaining a Dictionary of my own?

Comment: Why do you need/wamt to do this? If it's for programmatically changing the presentation culture, remember that Silverlight always uses the culture of the client OS that it's being run on.

Comment: I have the culture with me in "en-us" format while I need to pass it as LCID to a web-service (the web-service is not owned by me, hence i cannot change there)